# Getting static data for Flash app with JSON or XML - caching or not?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, json, javascript

I've flash app and i've static data (like ~18.0KB) for it which aren't changed often so I was wondering how to better get them. The static data may be in XML or JSON. One of my ideas was to put the static data in .js file within a function which would return them in JSON list and the other one was to return them in XML (as I like to work with XML more in Flash) somehow. But I'm not sure if it possible to put XML stuff in JS file to return them when function is called.. Or is XML pages also cached in browser and I will get the same performance result which I would get with cached JS files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the data in an XML file at server; it will be cached like any other file.

When you change the data, user would have to clear cache (**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>**) to load the modified version - this is true for any type of file.